# Определить начало перезагрузки в Linux

Tags: linux

По изменению каких системных файлов можно определить наверняка, что вот прямо сейчас поступила команда `reboot` (`shutdown -r`) и начинается перезагрузка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение я тогда нашел: в бесконечном цикле читать /proc/$PID/cmdline/ (все процессы) на наличие команд типа shutdown, reboot, init 0, init 6, etc. Причем отлавливало в 99% случаев.
Но это настолько дико выжирало процессор, что для меня такое решение оказалось неприемлемым. А при добавлении слипов отлавливать не успевало

Но мало ли кому пригодится

Answer (score 2):

По изменению системных файлов это определить невозможно. Более того, это вне ядра вообще невозможно определить. Косвенным указанием на перезагрузку служит получение `SIGTERM`, но и его можно выдать командой `kill`.

Кстати, если вы не отреагировали на `SIGTERM`, то за ним последует `SIGKILL`, на который отреагировать уже не удастся.

Comment: Я немного не договорил, решить задачу пытаюсь в php скрипте, висящем как демон, а функция pcntl_signal не поддерживается хостингом :(

Comment: Ну, тогда всё совсем плохо...